# PHP SQL login error

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page using php and sql.  This is my php code that gets the username and password data from mysql and checks if they are right so the user gets logged in. I'm getting this error:

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

on the line:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start();

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","user","pass");
  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "fail!". mysqli_connect_errnor();
  }

$first =$_POST['username'];
$last=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT count(user_id) as records FROM table WHERE username='$first' AND password='$last'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row['records'] == 1);
{
    $_SESSION['loggedIN'] =true;
    header("Location:logged.php");
    die();

}
else {

    $_SESSION['loggedIN'] = null;
    header("Location:home.php");
    die();

}


?>
```

Comment: table is a reserved word,are you sure your table name is table?Use backticks if so \`table\`.Also google prepared statements.

Comment: So you're attempting to use PDO, but you're still placing `$_POST` data directly into the query? Nice...

Comment: You can't just assume your query worked, you need to check for errors before `fetch()`ing.  `if($result === FALSE){ var_dump($db->errorInfo()); die; }`.  P.S. PDO doesn't magically make your queries injection-free, you need to be using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).  P.P.S. `mysqli_connect_errno` won't help you here.  You're using PDO not MySQLi.

Comment: Apart from the sql injection problem and the table name, you are using PDO but checking for mysqli errors...

Comment: And a plain-text password...

Answer (score 1):

try it with

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database","user","pass");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

makes it harder to miss errors that might occur.
And then as - Stanyer pointed out - don't put the parameters directly into your query but pass them as ..parameters.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT count(user_id) as records FROM `table` WHERE username=? AND password=?');
$stmt->execute( array($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) );
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```